# Loading assembly via reflection succeeds, Add-Type does not

Tags: .net, powershell

I'm using a .net assembly in Powershell. This code works successfully:

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("E:\Workspaces\RTE\dh.PSP.Common\Mainline\Source\dh.Common.MetaData\bin\dh.Common.Metadata.dll")
$marketMetadataRepository = New-Object dh.Common.Metadata.MarketMetadataRepository
```

Result:

> GAC    Version        Location
>
> ---    -------        --------                                                                                                                                                                                        False  v4.0.30319
>   E:\Workspaces\RTE\dh.PSP.Common\Mainline\Source\dh.Common.MetaData\bin\dh.Common.Metadata.dll

So one would think this would work successfully also:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName
"E:\Workspaces\RTE\dh.PSP.Common\Mainline\Source\dh.Common.MetaData\bin\dh.Common.Metadata.dll"
```

but no:

> Add-Type : Could not load file or assembly
>   'E:\Workspaces\RTE\dh.PSP.Common\Mainline\Source\dh.Common.MetaData\bin\dh.Common.Metadata.dll'
>   or one of its dependencies. The given assembly name or codebase  was
>   invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)

I'm confused as to why one method would work and another does not. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom()` or `[Reflection.Assembly]::Load()`?  I was under the impression that `LoadFile()` wasn't to be used specifically because it allows you to load multiple files with the same identity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-assemblyname` parameter of Add-Type expects an full or partial assembly name. Try using `-path` instead.